# Can't send an email using Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, laravel

Hello i'm trying to send an email from an app i'm building with Laravel using ajax when a button is pressed.

Here is my mail file

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'smtp',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => 465,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'ssl',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => '*******@gmail.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => '********',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

Controller function

```
public function sendMailReject(){

    $user = array(
        'email'=>'*****@gmail.com',
        'name'=>'Laravelovich'
    );

    // the data that will be passed into the mail view blade template
    $data = array(
        'detail'=>'Your awesome detail here',
        'name'  => 'nampi';
    );

    // use Mail::send function to send email passing the data and using the $user variable in the closure
    Mail::send('email.emailReject', $data, function($message) use ($user)
    {
        $message->from('*****@gmail.com', 'Site Admin');
        $message->to($user['email'], $user['name'])->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');
    });
}
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rejMail").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"sendMailReject",
            success:function(){
                alert("ok");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And finally my route

```
Route::get('sendMailReject','EmailController@sendMailReject');
```

When i see the log on the chrome console it gives me an internal error in the controller

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, you have following error in your controller:

```
$data = array(
    'detail' => 'Your awesome detail here',
    'name'   => 'nampi'; // <---
);
```

Remove the `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your config/mail.php:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'smtp',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => 587,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => array('address' = '******@gmail.com', 'name' = 'Site Admin'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => '*******@gmail.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => '********',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

In jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rejMail").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"sendMailReject",
            success:function(){
                alert("Mail sent successfully");
            },
            error:function() {
                alert('Error in sending mail');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Your routes.php

```
Route::get('sendMailReject','EmailController@sendMailReject');
```

In your controller

```
public function sendMailReject(){

    $user = array(
        'email'=>'*****@gmail.com',
        'name'=>'Laravelovich'
    );

    // the data that will be passed into the mail view blade template
    $data = array(
        'detail'=>'Your awesome detail here',
        'name'  => 'nampi'
    );

    // use Mail::send function to send email passing the data and using the $user variable in the closure
    Mail::send('email.emailReject', $data, function($message) use ($user)
    {
        $message->to($user['email'], $user['name'])->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');
    });

    echo true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. It works on localhost but on something like godaddy shared host, it does not work. 
From [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/send-email-on-shared-hosting)  discussion.

From another site...

GoDaddy does not let you send emails via external SMTP on a shared hosting plan.
Here's GoDaddy's own words:
We appreciate your feedback and apologize for any inconvenience, however, due to security reasons, we are not able to allow the use of external SMTP servers in a shared hosting environment. If you need additional SMTP relays, you would need to consider a virtual dedicated or dedicated server.
So.. I guess the short answer is, you need a better host.